# Pytest dependency - make one function to be dependent on the other

Tags: python, dependencies, pytest

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('feed', ['C', 'D'])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('file', ['foo.txt', 'boo.txt', 'doo.txt'])
def test_1(feed: Path, file: str):
    assert (Path(feed / file).is_file()), 'Not file'


@pytest.mark.parametrize('feed_C, feed_D', [('C', 'D')])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('file', ['foo.txt', 'boo.txt', 'doo.txt'])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('column', ['name', 'surname'])
def test_2(feed_C: Path, feed_D: Path, file: str, column: str):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(Path(feed_C / file), sep="\t")
    df2 = pd.read_csv(Path(feed_D / file), sep="\t")
    
    assert df1[column].equals(df2[column]), 'data frames are not equal.'
```

I have two test function `test_1` and `test_2`. `test_2` should be dependent on the `test_1`. But the iterations in both test are different.

test_1 iterations =>

1. foo.txt_C
2. foo.txt_D
3. boo.txt_C
4. boo.txt_D
5. doo.txt_C
6. doo.txt_D

test_2 iterations =>

1. name_foo.txt_C_D
2. name_boo.txt_C_D
3. name_doo.txt_C_D
4. surname_foo.txt_C_D
5. surname_boo.txt_C_D
6. surname_doo.txt_C_D

I want, for example, test iteration (name_foo.txt_C_D) in test_2 to be dependent on result of 1 and 2. For example, if foo.txt_C *or* foo.txt_ (even one of them), then name_foo.txt_C_D test iteration in test_2 will be SKIPPED. the same is for surname_foo.txt_C_D

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate test just two check if the paths are valid, you can do it in the same test. You also shouldn't create dependency between tests

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('feed_C, feed_D', [('C:', 'D:')])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('file', ['foo.txt', 'boo.txt', 'doo.txt'])
def test(feed_C: Path, feed_D: Path, file: str):
    path_c = Path(feed_C / file)
    assert path_c.is_file(), 'Not file'

    path_d = Path(feed_D / file)
    assert path_d.is_file(), 'Not file'

    df1 = pd.read_csv(path_c, sep="\t")
    df2 = pd.read_csv(path_d, sep="\t")
    assert df1.equals(df2), 'data frames are not equal.'
```